# Create Sort ID column as if Cascade Sorting two columns of data in excel

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, position

I have two columns, Days and Value. Trying to create an excel formula to populate third column that ID's what position that row would be in, if were to cascade sort the two columns. First by Value (smallest to greatest) and then Days (greatest to smallest)

| Days | Value | Desired_Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2500 | 0.01 | 7 |
| 1 | 0.01 | 6 |
| 500 | 2 | 4 |
| 100 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 100 | 3 |
| 2500 | 9300 | 2 |
| 1 | 9300 | 1 |

Sample data is pretty much already sorted as needed, but in actual file the values are all over the place. The ID Position is essentially to be a priority column. Though the table cannot actually be sorted on this particular sheet.

This seemed close, but unable to modify it accordingly.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-formula-to-track-a-sort-position/b8efbfa5-7ed9-4272-8f3c-ddfe04c00cb7

EDIT: I had the Desired Sort ID Values backwards.

Comment: What should the result be if two or more entries have identical values in both the Days and Value columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with Office 365 we can use sort to sort the array and then match to find where it lands:

```
=MATCH(A2&"|"&B2,BYROW(SORT(FILTER($A$2:$B$10000,$A$2:$A$10000<>""),{2,1},{-1,1}),LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN("|",,a))),0)
```

[image]

---

And just to get fancy with it we can spill the results instead of copying the formula down:

```
=LET(
    rng,FILTER($A$2:$B$10000,$A$2:$A$10000<>""),
    srt,SORT(rng,{2,1},{-1,1}),
    rng_brw,BYROW(rng,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN("|",,a))),
    srt_brw,BYROW(srt,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN("|",,a))),
    MATCH(rng_brw,srt_brw,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner !!  Your Answer is awesome!! I did have an error in my question and just edited the table. Is it possible to use your solution but reverse the ID Order? (So if sorted the ID Column the row with 2500 - 0.01 is at the top and the row 1 - 9300 is at the bottom.)

Comment: @Ben.Name it is not proper to edit one's question after getting answers.  It invalidates the answers and opens the answers to down votes because now their answer does not meet the question.  Usually one would try to fix the issue on their own and if not able, then would ask another question.  So in the future keep this in mind.  I will edit the post in a moment to make the change, since it is a simple adjustment.

Comment: Understood. I figured it out and accepted the answer. -Thank you. Changed {2,1},{1,-1} to {2,1},{-1,1}

Answer (score 3):

Alternate solution without use of LAMBDA, but also requiring Office 365:

```
=LET(range,  A2:B8,
     seq,    SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),
     srt,    TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(seq,range),{3,2},{-1,1}),,1),
XMATCH(seq,srt))
```

`srt` sorts range it's rows by Values smallest to greatest and days greatest to smallest.

Then it matches the position of the row in `srt`.